# Adding a timeout to a javascript rotation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code working (in Firefox & Safari only - no worries it's a subtle effect that doesn't need perfect cross-browser compatibility).

HTML

`<span id="rotate_star"></div>`

Javscript

```
<script>
    var count = 0;
    function rotate() {
      var elem2 = document.getElementById('rotate_star');
      elem2.style.MozTransform = 'rotate('+count+'deg)';
      elem2.style.WebkitTransform = 'rotate('+count+'deg)';
      if (count==360) { count = 0 }
      count+=10;
      window.setTimeout(rotate, 30);
    }
    window.setTimeout(rotate, 100);
</script>
```

I'll be honest, I'm not the most savvy person in the world when it comes to javascript.  I want this animation to repeat in an infinite loop but I want it to delay for 5 seconds every time it makes a complete 360 degree turn.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to modify it a tiny bit, and it should do what you want. Try this:

```
<script>
    var count = 0;
    function rotate() {
      var elem2 = document.getElementById('rotate_star');
      elem2.style.MozTransform = 'rotate('+count+'deg)';
      elem2.style.WebkitTransform = 'rotate('+count+'deg)';
      if (count==360) { 
          count = 10;
          window.setTimeout(rotate, 5000);
      } else {
          count += 10;
          window.setTimeout(rotate, 30);
      }
    }
    window.setTimeout(rotate, 100);
</script>
```